# error from infura test net is empty from react-native app

Tags: react-native, ethereum

I use this to connect to the infura rospten from a `react-native mobile app`:

```
const url = 'https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/xxx';
this.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(url))
```

when I call a contract, I get:

```
Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""]
```

why is the error empty?

Using the same method connect to the local ganache, and it works.

Is it because of the authorization or the network configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `/v3` part from your URL

Convert

```
const url = 'https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/xxx';
```

To:

```
const url = 'https://ropsten.infura.io/xxx';
```

Also, are you signing the transaction before connecting to infura. You need to sign transaction for address before making any transaction request. You can use [HD-wallet-provider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/truffle-hdwallet-provider) and use mnemonic which was provided to you during your account creation.